# CodeIgniter SELECT with 2 JOINS - how to get the correct id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

The Problem Summary:
I am doing a join from 3 tables using CodeIgniter's Active Record Class. All 3 tables have 'ID' as their primary key. How do I get the correct ID to output? I tried to figure out how to do an alias in the select statement but couldn't get it to work.

The Code:

(Controller)

```
public function index()
{
$data['call_reports'] = $this->call_reports_model->get_call_reports();
$data['title'] = 'All Call Reports';
$this->load->view('call_reports/templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('call_reports/index', $data);
$this->load->view('call_reports/templates/footer');
}
```

(Model)

```
public function get_call_reports()
{
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('call_reports');
$this->db->join('employees', 'employees.ID=call_reports.employee_ID');
$this->db->join('customers', 'customers.ID=call_reports.customer_ID');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
}
```

(index)

```
<?php foreach($call_reports as $call_reports_item): ?>
<p><?php echo $call_reports_item['name'] ?></p> <!—Result: name from employee table -->
<p><?php echo $call_reports_item['CUSNM'] ?></p> <!—Result: name from customer table -->
<?php echo $call_reports_item['ID'] ?> ***<!—RESULTS IN EMPLOYEE ID -->***
<?php endforeach ?>
```

The Problem Line of Code:

```
<?php echo $call_reports_item['ID'] ?> ***<!—RESULTS IN EMPLOYEE ID -->***
```

I want this to be the call report ID not the employee ID. How do I fix?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using `$call_reports_item['call_reports.ID']`? It's also a bad idea to use the "ID" name for every primary key in your database.

Comment: @Twister1002 I did try using `$call_reports_item['call_reports.ID']` with this result: Message: Undefined index: call_reports.ID

Comment: `var_dump($call_reports_item)`; What's there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just standard SQL:

```
$this->db->from('call_reports cr');
```

Then do selects of variables you want:

```
$this->db->select('cr.id, ...');
```

and you would reference the value as `cr.id` in your result. For each table just add an alias after it (keep it simple, like cr, e, or c (customers).

Enjoy

**Edit**
Based on your response, you could also use **[method chaining](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#chaining)** to reduce using `$this->db->` for each line. The catch is it makes your code less readable, but for simple calls it is just fine:

```
$this->db->select('cr.ID,cr.call_date,cr.objective,cr.comments,c.CBRCD,e.name,c.‌​CUSNM');
$this->db->from('call_reports cr')->join('employees e', 'e.ID=cr.employee_ID')->join('customers c', 'c.ID=cr.customer_ID');
```

I've left it on 2 lines (could do it on 1), but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you very much, your advice was very helpful and I found the solution because of it. This is what I ended up doing and it worked like a charm. Thank you to everybody who responded.

    `$this->db->from('call_reports cr');
    $this->db->join('employees e', 'e.ID=cr.employee_ID');
    $this->db->join('customers c', 'c.ID=cr.customer_ID');
    $this->db->select('cr.ID,cr.call_date,cr.objective,cr.comments,c.CBRCD,e.name,c.CUSNM');`

Comment: glad it helped, I've outlined **method chaining** for you as well, something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

in  your select try:

```
$this->db->select('employees.*, customers.*, call_reports.*');
```

and then use:

```
$call_reports_item['call_reports.ID']
```

Comment: problem with this is you are selecting ALL columns which is not really needed. Never use `*` unless you are just doing a quick test.

Comment: The code sample posted in the original post selects all fields across all 3 tables. My code is an equivalent representation of what Joe was trying to achieve. So, how do you know not ALL columns are needed anyway?

Comment: @raj your suggestion was equivalent to what I was trying to do and it probably would have worked. However, Jakub was correct in assuming I didn't need all the fields from 3 tables so I used aliases and made my select statement specific to the fields I needed. Thank you for your post.